# Laravel data best practices

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm new at Laravel and I want to know what best practices are for that :

I have a bunch of item I got with my query. It returns me something like that :

```
[{"id_equipement":24,"id_typeequipement":5, "imgequipement":xxxx}, 
{"id_equipement":30,"id_typeequipement":8, "imgequipement":xxxx}]
```

I have now 15 div to fill (see image below). One div represents one type and I want to know how to check if my first record goes to my second div background image, my second record goes to my third div...

[image]

I don't really know how to split in order to check...

Here is my html code:

```
                                        <div class="item-frame-vertical" id="item-hat">
                                            <div class="item-inner-frame"
                                                 style="background-image: url({{ asset('images/item_display/headgear.png') }})"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item-frame-vertical" id="item-necklace" data-target="lol">
                                            <div class="item-inner-frame"
                                                 style="background-image: url({{ asset('images/item_display/amulet.png') }})"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item-frame-vertical" id="item-chest">
                                            <div class="item-inner-frame"
                                                 style="background-image: url({{ asset('images/item_display/breastplate.png') }})"></div>
                                        </div>
```

How can I check :

If the first record is type "5", it belongs to my 8th div

I was intending to do 15 query and give my controller 15 array and check for each div if there is a single record but I'm not sure this is the best way to do it because I must make 15 queries...

The way I'm doing it, I feel that I have to go through my result 15 times with a foreach and then check the type like :

```
@foreach ($entries as $entry)
 if($entry->type_equipement == 5)
{
$img = $entry->img_equipement;
}
else
{
$img = images/item_display/breastplate.png
}
@endforeach
<div class="item-inner-frame" style="background-image: 
url({{ asset('$img') }})"></div>
 </div>
```

**EDIT :**

To be more precise... If I have the :

- record with 'id_typeequipement' 5 I must change the background of the div 'item-hat' by 'img_equipement' from my record
- record with 'id_typeequipement' 7 I must change the background of the div 'item-chest' by 'img_equipement' from my record

and this, for 15 div

Comment: you just check the type as you did,and then add the '8th' div, what 8th div exactly?

Comment: I edited the post to be more clear!

Comment: then you just need to loop through the entries

Comment: All of them? So I must do 15 foreach with 15 if statement for each div? That was my first thoughts but felt It was not a good way to go

Comment: i would do this in the controller not the view

Comment: checkout the collection documentation, cuz the db will send you collections of items: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections

Comment: If this is going to be a recurring issue, you might find it easier to add some sort of `sort` or `sequence` column to your database, so that the data can be retrieved in the required order.

Comment: I did a switch case in my controller and return an array with the image I need with fix position so... I tried to avoid a lot of loop
This is not going to be recurring, thanks for help !